# How to get notified by mail when rows are inserted into table?

Tags: mysql, jsp, email, servlets

I made an online store coded in JSP and tables stored in MysQl. I'm using servlet and classes. I would like to get notify by mail at `admin@domain.com` when an order is inserted in the database.

Likewise, the customer should receive the order confirmation to the email they entered when they submit the form.

I would like to get feedback on how to do such a task. What's the best practice? I hope to not get back fire with this question because I`m aware there are several answers possible.

Basically, I`m just looking for the easiest and fastest implementation without too much hassle!

The form contains very sensitive and confidential data like address and such. But, since our customers can track their orders on the site, the data should not be sent, for security purposes. Just a message to confirm the reception of their order.

Please guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Hibernate i would recommend you using an entity listener, specially with a **@PostPersist** callback. You can read about it in [Chapter 6. Entity listeners and Callback methods](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html).

The email part can be done using the [JavaMail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html).

You can check an example of sending an email in [Sending an Email using the JavaMail API](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/javamail/javamail.html).

Hope it helps!