# Sending two different emails at the same time using JavaMail API

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm using JavaMail API to notify the administrator when there's [data insertion in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687280/how-to-get-notified-by-mail-when-rows-are-inserted-into-table)

This works fine. The admin receives the notification of data entry.

However, I also need to notify the client by sending him a confirmation at the same time, but it does not work. The customer does not receive any confirmation. I also want to paste the confirmation number in the subject. Could it be related to port conflict?

```
EmailAdmin.sendEmail(to, subject, body);
EmailCustomer.sendEmail(EM, subjectsub, bodybod, CN);
```

EmailAdmin.java

```
    package session;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class EmailAdmin {

    private final int port = 465;
    private final String host = "smtp.server.com";
    private final String from = "admin@domain.com";
    private final boolean auth = true;
    private final String username = "admin@domain.com";
    private final String password = "password";
    private final Protocol protocol = Protocol.SMTPS;
    private final boolean debug = true;

    public void sendEmail(String to, String subject, String body) {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);

        switch (protocol) {
            case SMTPS:
                props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", true);
                break;
            case TLS:
                props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
                break;
        }

        Authenticator authenticator = null;
        if (auth) {
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
            authenticator = new Authenticator() {
                private final PasswordAuthentication pa = new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                @Override
                public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return pa;
                }
            };
        }

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, authenticator);
        session.setDebug(debug);

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        try {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setSentDate(new Date());
            message.setText(body);

            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

EmailCustomer.java

```
    package session;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class EmailCustomer {

    private final int port = 465;
    private final String host = "smtp.server.com";
    private final String from = "admin@domain.com";
    private final boolean auth = true;
    private final String username = "admin@domain.com";
    private final String password = "password";
    private final Protocol protocol = Protocol.SMTPS;
    private final boolean debug = true;

    public void sendEmail(String EM, String subjectsub, String bodybod, String CN) {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);

        switch (protocol) {
            case SMTPS:
                props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", true);
                break;
            case TLS:
                props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
                break;
        }

        Authenticator authenticator = null;
        if (auth) {
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
            authenticator = new Authenticator() {
                private final PasswordAuthentication pa = new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                @Override
                public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return pa;
                }
            };
        }

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, authenticator);
        session.setDebug(debug);

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        try {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(EM)};
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
            message.setSubject(subject, CN);
            message.setSentDate(new Date());
            message.setText(body);

            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also show the part of the code where you call the `sendEmail` methods.

Comment: The two classes seems to be identical, with the exception of char set. don't you think you could do better then have duplicate code dozens of lines long ?

Comment: To find out if the problem is a port conflict, all you need to do is to only send the second email (the one that's currently not working). If that works, then you have an answer. Right?

Comment: First of all you should check your SMTP server, because servers always tries to block sender which sends more than 1 mail per 30 seconds, for instance (it depends to server configuration). It's a one of spam filter rule and it might be disabled for specific email by a SMTP server admin. If you already disabled this rules I guess in SMTP server logs you should find an answer (there are a lot of information about email sending tries,recipients etc.).

Comment: `catch (MessagingException ex) {        }` Swallowing Exceptions - **bad** idea ... I bet you'd get some info on what's happening if you logged them.

Comment: You're turning on [JavaMail session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug), so what does the debug output show?